# Maximum Recursion depth exceeded when installing Django Fixture

Tags: django, django-models, fixtures

When running a Django unit test, it try's to install a fixture (initial_data.json) to the db, but fails everytime due to `Runtime Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling Python object`

Any idea what's going on?

Edit: Django 1.2.3 and Python 2.7

[image]

Comment: Posting the contents of the fixture might help.

Comment: Posting the version of Django you're using might help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frequently get frustratingly opaque errors from `manage.py loaddata` and related operations like the one you've illustrated here.

One possible cause is: fixtures generated from `manage.py dumpdata > fixture.json` -- sans any qualifying app names -- are full of extraneous records which you may not need for your tests.

You may wish to regenerate your initial_data.json file, excluding some or all of the following:

- Admin log entries
- Content-types
  (these automatically repopulate when
  `manage.py syncdb` and the like are
  invoked)
- Sessions
- django.contrib.auth
  permissions
- Any models, or entire apps, that are
  specifically ancilliary to your tests (e.g.
  I generally omit django-tagging
  data, the tables for which can grow large
  very quickly, and whose content is often orthogonal to my tests)

If you need everything in your fixture, you can also try breaking it into two or more fixture files.